# How can I silence ALL output from a command in a batch file?

Tags: cmd.exe

I figured that 2>NUL at the end of DOS commands was enough, but it seems some messages, some error, still get through. So how can I cut off all output whatsoever? Or should I just forget it and allow output through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your batch file with:

`@ECHO OFF`

And redirect all command output by appending:

`>NUL 2>&1`

This redirects "Standard Out" (1) to NUL and redirects "Standard Error" (2) to (1).

Comment: Do you know if this also works for 7-Zip? I've inserted it at the end of a 7-Zip command and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

The `2>NUL` redirection suppresses error output, but has no effect on standard output messages.

The usual way to redirect both is `>NUL 2>&1`, and you should use this form when redirecting both to a file. However, for the `NUL` device, you could also use the marginally less efficient `>NUL 2>NUL`.

See [this link](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for a full description of redirection options.